# Creating a check that needs to loop outwards from the middle of 3 variables ( x y z )

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, minecraft

```
for (int ix = x - r; ix < x + r + 1; ix++) {
    for (int iz = z - r; iz < z + r + 1; iz++) {
        for (int iy = y - r; iy < y + r + 1; iy++) {
                       // if ix,iy,iz = something blah blah (this part isn't needed)
        }                           
    }
}
```

Ok, now here's the issue. The current code above gets an x,y,z and r (range). It's job is to reference through the "cube" until meets a certain condition I've set. The problem lies in the fact that it starts on the outside of the cube and progresses from 1 corner to another corner basically.

I'm looking for a way (my math/java is not liking me atm) to start at a pos and loop outwards from that pos (including the pos itself) until it reaches the outermost bounds of the cube.

So if we gave everything fake values, lets use   x = 5, y = 5, z = 5, r = 2
the code should check 5,5,5 - 4,5,5 6,5,5 5,6,5 5,4,5 etc etc basically iterating through every thing to outwards from the center.

The command is called FindNearest, but technically it's acting like FindFurthest atm.

I hope I gave enough detail and would love if someone could toss some snippets or working code at me as this is frustrating for the last hour or so. I don't wanna have 10 if checks in the middle of the for loops or random stuff like that, I'm looking for a clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate out from the center by doing something like this:

```
for (ix = x, xsign = 1, xstep = 1; 
     (ix >= x - r) && (ix <= x + r);
     ix += xsign * xstep, xsign = -xsign, xstep++)
```

So `ix` for your example will go from 5 to 6 to 4 to 7, etc.  You can just nest loops like these and you'll get what you're looking for, at least if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Well if I could give you an upvote I would, but I need 15 rep first O.o   The answer however is definitely acceptable.

Comment: If you nest two loops like the one above, it'll search close-to-far along a row or column, then move in close again for the next row or column. That is if you have two candidate items and you want the closest, it will choose one at say, 0,4 before one at 1,1 if x is your outer loop and y your inner one.